# Not Able to Get Deleted File From Git Commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I deleted a few files from my rails app using git.  They were committed and pushed to Heroku (live).  Now, I would like to bring a couple of them back, but I'm having trouble doing so.  I've been using git for awhile and not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I've checked a couple of git pages to be sure this should work.

The files are not in my local repository, but are in git.  Git lists them (showing one in my example), but wont let me retrieve them.

I found the commit and the following shows the file in that logged commit:

```
jdc44@jdc44-Kudu:~/Websites/myapp$ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 9c88a26ade871
...
app/models/fitness/weight.rb
...
```

Trying to revert the weight.rb file:

```
jdc44@jdc44-Kudu:~/Websites/myapp$ git checkout 9c88a26ade871 -- app/models/fitness/weight.rb
error: pathspec 'app/models/fitness/weight.rb' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Trying to see if I can show the file:

```
jdc44@jdc44-Kudu:~/Websites/myapp$ git show 9c88a26ade871:app/models/fitness/weight.rb
fatal: Path 'app/models/fitness/weight.rb' does not exist in '9c88a26ade871'
```

**edited**

```
jdc44@jdc44-Kudu:~/Websites/myapp$ git diff-tree -r 9c88a26ade871
9c88a26ade8719069ecd852b27a6bb354a4915f2
:100644 000000 ba4631114edea7c66e8f87109dc6e65fb95b7a6c 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  app/controllers/fitness/weights_controller.rb
:100644 000000 cfca94348c82c4a6fab1c789245582cc3086f786 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  app/models/fitness/weight.rb
:100644 000000 4963ad7f7939f74606b5356e264dc20c1382165b 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  app/views/fitness/weights/_form.html.erb
:100644 000000 9c3f9b7f3f7177d7ba4b5609f3aa5c0769b7d1e1 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  app/views/fitness/weights/create.html.erb
:100644 000000 3b9e22e45116d15eab5a494ce342307cac1ce405 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  app/views/fitness/weights/delete.html.erb
:100644 000000 8e3ec02483b68e8f5a2e8de23f569dbd359d3d95 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  app/views/fitness/weights/destroy.html.erb
:100644 000000 d59b3be0408d467bcedf1ac43e82916e338d30d9 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  app/views/fitness/weights/edit.html.erb
:100644 000000 84a1dd6e73c35a612e4e52476d440fd7a659b657 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  app/views/fitness/weights/index.html.erb
:100644 000000 4980c3adecc0b86528d99f7828c5369f185a1ba2 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  app/views/fitness/weights/new.html.erb
:100644 000000 eb61383cc1e256e386357930d9db8bf88379ad2c 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  app/views/fitness/weights/show.html.erb
:100644 000000 43f9c0adea7cff97c240bd02db495e908231bfd4 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D  app/views/fitness/weights/update.html.erb
```

Comment: Could you show us the output of just `git diff-tree 9c88a26ade871` please?

Comment: Marco Luzzara -- I edited my original post to show the output of the command you requested.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `-r` option, could you re-edit? Thanks. I would like to see not only the filename but the full line of that specific file.

Comment: Marco Luzzara  Thank you again for your time and comments.  I re-edited my original post with your command wit the `-r`   For space, I only listed the files referring to the weight model, controllers, views....

Comment: jdc44@jdc44-Kudu:~/Websites/myapp$ git checkout 9c88a26ade871^ -- app/models/fitness/weight.rb     This works.  The commit before this one - 9c88a... had the file, so adding the ^ to the 'checkout' command works.  Duh!!

Answer (score 1):

Each commit in Git is a complete snapshot of all the files at that moment. 9c88a26ade871 does not have the file app/models/fitness/weight.rb because that's the commit where you deleted it.

You need to get it from the commit *before* you deleted it. 9c88a26ade871^. See [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

`git checkout 9c88a26ade871^ -- app/models/fitness/weight.rb`

Or use the simpler `git restore` (checkout was split into restore and switch).

`git restore --source 9c88a26ade871^ app/models/fitness/weight.rb`